# Set parameters in traefik as ingress controller( reverse proxy )

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, traefik-ingress

i'm trying to set up traefik as a reverse proxy. I've followed the tutorial on this web site [Traefik as Ingress Controller for Your Kubernetes](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c) .

I'm currently a little lost in the configuration to define the proxy parameters in the **proxy.conf** file.

I don't understand how to **set** the listening port of proxy **8080** on ip **127.0.0.0.1** and the **domain** definition my-service.my-company.com.

i added all the file in the gist : [you will find it here](https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/0e17df71fb820726cc1face174f1f165)

thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: What is this proxy.conf file? What are you trying to achieve? What are the errors you are seeing?

Comment: you will find below my  [traefik-configmap.yaml](https://gist.github.com/zyriuse75/c1dd279b8e7f629f2e49738118f5885e)